# Performing calculations on every pair of fields

Tags: python, perl, bash, awk, calculated-columns

For genetic analyses I'm trying to convert a 2-probability file (10gb) to 3-probabilities file . basically i have to insert a third column after every 2 other instances, this third column can be calculated as 1-(first instance + second instance).  How would you do this?

From:

```
0.800   0.200   0.000   0.200   0.800   0.200
0.000   0.900   0.000   0.900   0.000   0.900
0.900   0.010   0.900   0.010   0.770   0.010
```

(the file contains many columns and rows)

to

```
0.800   0.200   0.000   0.000   0.200   0.800   0.800   0.200   0.000
0.000   0.900   0.100   0.000   0.900   0.100   0.000   0.900   0.100
0.900   0.010   0.090   0.900   0.010   0.090   0.770   0.010   0.220
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `awk`:

```
awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i+=2)$(i+1)=$(i+1)OFS sprintf("%.3f",1-$(i+1)-$i)}1' OFS='\t' file
0.800   0.200   0.000   0.000   0.200   0.800   0.800   0.200   0.000
0.000   0.900   0.100   0.000   0.900   0.100   0.000   0.900   0.100
0.900   0.010   0.090   0.900   0.010   0.090   0.770   0.010   0.220
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#! /usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

*ARGV = *DATA;  # for demo only

while (<>) {
  chomp;

  my @fields = split;
  my @output;
  while (@fields >= 2) {
    my($x,$y) = splice @fields, 0, 2;

    push @output, $x, $y, sprintf "%.3f", 1.0 - ($x + $y);
  }

  print join(" " x 3, @output, @fields), "\n";
}

__DATA__
0.800   0.200   0.000   0.200   0.800   0.200
0.000   0.900   0.000   0.900   0.000   0.900
0.900   0.010   0.900   0.010   0.770   0.010
```

Output:

```
0.800   0.200   0.000   0.000   0.200   0.800   0.800   0.200   0.000
0.000   0.900   0.100   0.000   0.900   0.100   0.000   0.900   0.100
0.900   0.010   0.090   0.900   0.010   0.090   0.770   0.010   0.220
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict; use warnings;

my $template = join "\t", ("%.3f")x3;

while (<>) {
  my @fields = split;
  @fields % 2 == 0 or die "Uneven number of fields";
  while (my ($x, $y) = splice @fields, 0, 2) {
    printf $template, $x, $y, 1 - ($x + $y);
    print  @fields ? "\t" : "\n";
  }
}
```

Usage: `perl script.pl <input >output-file`.